# how to set character in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

i am designing a 3d game using three.js library. I want to move character of game automatically on the values from outcome of drawn dice. how it is possible.
how to code for setting up between dice value and character of game.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a general question forum. In order for people to help you, you need to show some effort and some code. What have you tried and how it is failing.

Comment: Now i am working on Designing phase. I do not write code yet but i have full planning of game and according to it i divide my game in different modules and my problem is one of that module.i can briefly explain each step but firstly i need a suggestion that which function help me to configure setting between automatically running of character over dice values

Comment: this is a link http://www.kongregate.com/games/mehdyrabieey/snakes-and-ladders-3d i want to set my character in same way.